# Get Value from a Input Box in Selenium with no attribute in markup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, protractor-net

I have the following markup and in the browser it displays 'XYZ' but I see no attribute that I can use to grab it using Selenium and C#. Does it have to do with this being an angular element ?

```
<input class="primary-input ng-untouched ng-pristine" formcontrolname="EmployeeCode" maxlength="4" name="EmployeeCode" placeholder="" disabled="">
```

I tried

```
string val = Driver.FindElement(By.Name("EmployeeCode")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Comment: What does your code return? It looks like the right code. If it's not working, my guess is that the form/field is loaded with data a few seconds after the page loads through some background process so you might need to wait until the value is not empty... that would be one option.

Comment: what does protractor have to do with? will protractor's syntax help you?

Comment: It is angular generated so I thought there could be a protractor solution to it @SergeyPleshakov